# Retrive json Data in javascript for Phonegap Project

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, cordova

i am trying to retrieve JSON data from wordpress blog. I used JSON API plugin to get the JSON object.

Please check my code. Its showing error status 0. And not able to retrieve the data.

```
    var xmlhttp;

window.onload = function(){

        document.addEventListener("deviceready",init,false);
    }
    function init(){

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.foduu.com/api/get_recent_posts/", false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = dataReturn;
    }
    function dataReturn(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                var jsonResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
                jsonResponse  = eval("("+jsonResponse+")")  
                alert("jsonResponse.count_total");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("could not connect and Status:" + xmlhttp.status);
            }
    }
```

Please help me with this.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data comes from a domain (www.foduu.com) other than where your page is coming from, the call is considered to be a cross-domain call. XMLHttpRequest will not let such requests go through (for security purposes). There are two ways to work around this limitation, and both require the server to opt-in. The first is to use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing); the second (which works in your case, since you're issuing a GET request) is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

I tried sending a request to the site (using Fiddler) with a CORS headers (Origin) and the response does not contain any CORS-related response, so this service in particular doesn't support that protocol. It does, however, support JSONP (if you send a request using Fiddler to `http://www.foduu.com/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=cb` you'll see a response wrapped in a `cb(...)` call).

What you should do then is to use that in your page. You can use JSONP in "pure" javascript, by creating a `<script>` element and adding it to the DOM, but you'll get easier results if you use a library such as jQuery which makes it easier to make JSONP calls to the service.

Comment: Can i use this in phonegap?